# What can I do to make clang correctly mark implicitly-generated constructors as deleted?

Tags: c++, clang, code-generation

I've been trying to do some code generation using clang (not libclang), and there's one problem that have been bothering me for days.

I have a class that contains a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr`s, with no explicitly defined/deleted/defaulted copy or move constructors. It has a defaulted default constructor and an explicit constructor that accepts a `vector`. Clang does generate a copy constructor for the class automatically, but it doesn't mark it as deleted ([`FunctionDecl::isDeleted`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html)).

I believe that there must be something that I'm not doing that triggers clang to check if it should be deleted. Looking into the code of `clang::Sema` it seems that some kind of checking is performed in `Sema::DeclareImplicitCopyConstructor` (more specifically, `SpecialMemberDeletionInfo::shouldDeleteForClassSubobject`).

Is my assumption correct? If so, what should I do to manually trigger these checks?

Here's my code used to parse the file:

```
clang::CompilerInstance _compiler;
std::unique_ptr<clang::CompilerInvocation> invocation = ...;


_compiler.createDiagnostics();
_compiler.setInvocation(std::move(invocation));
_compiler.setTarget(clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(
    _compiler.getDiagnostics(), _compiler.getInvocation().TargetOpts
));

_compiler.createFileManager();
_compiler.createSourceManager(_compiler.getFileManager());
_compiler.createPreprocessor(clang::TU_Complete);
_compiler.getPreprocessor().getBuiltinInfo().initializeBuiltins(
    _compiler.getPreprocessor().getIdentifierTable(), *_compiler.getInvocation().getLangOpts()
); // this is necessary

_compiler.createASTContext();

assert_true(!_compiler.getFrontendOpts().Inputs.empty(), "no input file");


_ast_visitor visitor(reg);
_compiler.setASTConsumer(llvm::make_unique<_ast_consumer>(visitor));

if (_compiler.getFrontendOpts().Inputs.size() > 1) {
    std::cerr << "warning: main file not unique\n";
}
const clang::FileEntry *file =
    _compiler.getFileManager().getFile(_compiler.getFrontendOpts().Inputs[0].getFile());
_compiler.getSourceManager().setMainFileID(_compiler.getSourceManager().createFileID(
    file, clang::SourceLocation(), clang::SrcMgr::C_User
));

_compiler.getDiagnosticClient().BeginSourceFile(_compiler.getLangOpts(), &_compiler.getPreprocessor());
clang::ParseAST(_compiler.getPreprocessor(), &_compiler.getASTConsumer(), _compiler.getASTContext());
_compiler.getDiagnosticClient().EndSourceFile();
```

**EDIT**: My mistake. The vector contains `unique_ptr`s, not `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: Why do you expect the copy constructor to be deleted?

Comment: A vector of shared pointers is copyable. You haven't declared any move constructors/operators or copy constructors/operators so the copy constructor is implicitly declared. Given your description of the class, the copy constructor should not be deleted and clang is behaving correctly. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Comment: A copy constructor will be implicitly generated, unless it is suppressed somehow (e.g. a base class or member without a copy constructor or with a private copy constructor,  using the `=delete` syntax in C++11 and later).    It's not a good idea to suppress a copy constructor of something that will be stored in a `std::vector`, since `std::vector` requires ability to copy or move its elements.

Comment: @Kerndog73 @Peter My mistake. The vector contains `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same problem with clang not marking implicitly deleted default constructors as such.

Comment: @Peter No - I don't think that the issue is clang not marking them, but rather that the copy constructor is still defined but also deleted. Someone also pointed out that `std::is_copy_constructible<std::unique_ptr<...>>` is `true` - the expression is well-formed even if it fails to compile. Clang probably only checks when the constructor is actually called, and only then it emits an error (I'm not sure how exactly this works but that's my guess).